# How to animate a folding carton using only the vertices in edit mode?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, vertices, keyframes, object-mode

I am trying to animate a folding carton using only the vertices in edit mode, I find it easier for me. I tried following a video on Youtube ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyj0sJVd3Lw&list=PL1ufR-_dSlrGa-rN23kR_C0ACjpi-38JE&index=70&t=0s ) on how to do it but its in object mode, in edit mode I cannot insert a key frame :(

I would love to achieve what this package designer is doing ( https://www.behance.net/gallery/91695235/Organic-Soap-Packaging?tracking_source=search_projects_recommended%7Cpackage%20blender ), if you look at the animation video and what software tools he made it in; its Blender.

This would be a huge help if anyone out there know hows to I cannot find anything else.

*** If you can answer this question and not relate it to another answered question that would be better because sometimes the related answers are outdated. I have the 2.82a version ***

Here are some screenshots from my Mac I am having issues with:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason to not use Shape Keys? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html

Comment: Na, it needs to be done with an armature... Shape keys interpolates linear position so rotations will look bad.

Comment: did you check this tutorial that uses AnimAll addon? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvRA6z3z5bI

Comment: I agree with Jackdaw, this should be done with bones. You also probably want to use more than one vert on the joint, so that you con solidify and not collide with the other walls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this tutorial that uses *AnimAll addon*? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvRA6z3z5bI